# Creating variables depending of another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variables

For a school project we have to write a mini game. I got stuck when I tried to create new variables in a loop. I wrote a code where the user has to give the number of the players, and the Idea was to create new variables in a loop for each player. My question would be 1st : Is it even possible? 2nd : I want to store more information in a variable ( weapon, vest etc...) , so should I prefer using dictionary?

Comment: You could create a list of lists, where each sublist will hold data for each player. But you need to elaborate more and provide some sample code in order to fully address your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: Make a list, and use subsequent elements of that list. You can't create a variable with the same name twice.

2nd: I would go with a dictionary.

E.G.:

```
playerdata= []
for player in numplayers:
   playerdata.append({'playerID':player, 'weapon':'bow'})
```